# How do you theme Sharepoint 2019 with Modern exp?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019

My question is quite simple: how do you do (or which strategy do you have) when you theme a SP2019 Modern in prod env?

Since site design doesnt work in SP2019, I wonder what the easiest thing would be for site admins to change the colors etc on their sites, and newly created.

Upload a customized theme in the classic look, and use that for the modern sites maybe?

Answer (score 2):

You can [upload custom color palettes and font schemes to the Theme Gallery](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-deploy-a-custom-theme-in-sharepoint), and then use PnP PowerShell to apply the theme in SharePoint Server 2019.

The sample script should look like:

```
#Parameters
$SiteURL= "<SiteURL>"
 
#Connect to SP19
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credential (Get-Credential) #-UseWebLogin
 
#Change Set Theme
Set-PnPTheme -ColorPaletteUrl "/_catalogs/theme/15/palette008.spcolor" -BackgroundImageUrl "/_layouts/15/images/image_bg008.jpg" -FontSchemeUrl "/_catalogs/theme/15/fontscheme003.spfont"
```

Reference: [Set-PnPTheme.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnptheme?view=sharepoint-ps)

Comment: Thank you for the reply!